# In VSCode, how do I multi-cursor the ending of all symbols?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to add a suffix to all occurrences of a variable in a file (eg. pluralizing a variable `number` --> `numbers`).

VSCode offers a multiselect option thru the default "cmd+d", or `editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch`. However, after I do this over all occurrences of `number`, the entire variable is selected. I really just need the cursor to be at the very end, so I can add an `s`. I would like not have to retype `numbers`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I use a regex:

```
\b(var1|var2|var3)\b
```

And I replace it with the same content $1 (since I capture the variable name in a group with `()`) followed by 's': `$1s`

Comment: Probably need another \b at the beginning so you don't get words with the var name embedded somewhere in them.

Comment: @Mark Agreed. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I would just copy the variable first.  So:

1. Double-click your variable and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> selects all occurences
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and add your 's'

The regex method is better if you have a few variables to change, but not if you have only one or two to change.  Really simple to create a macro if you would be doing this a lot - you could get it down to a single keychord.

[This unfortunately selects occurrences of var1 and someOtherVar1 (the Var1 part) - so if this is a problem better to use a regex as it is easier to exclude instances of the var1 term appearing within another word, like someVar1 that you do not intend to change.]